# Partition are not getting assigned to Kafka consumer instance

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

When I start consumer with single instance it is show in consumer group but it is not consuming data from topic. After that if I start another consumer and my first consumer start consuming data but latest consumer instance doesn't have any partition assigned to it.

below is the info log when first consumer instance starts.

> INFO:kafka.client:Bootstrapping cluster metadata from [(u'kafka-broker1.ap-south-1.staging.internal', 9092, 0)]
>   INFO:kafka.conn:: connecting to 172.31.1.66:9092
>   INFO:kafka.client:Bootstrap succeeded: found 3 brokers and 19 topics.
>   INFO:kafka.conn:: Closing connection. 
>   INFO:kafka.conn:: connecting to 172.31.1.148:9092
>   INFO:kafka.conn:Broker version identifed as 0.11.0
>   INFO:kafka.conn:Set configuration api_version=(0, 11, 0) to skip auto check_version requests on startup
>   INFO:kafka.consumer.subscription_state:Subscribing to pattern: /events/
>   INFO:kafka.conn:: connecting to 172.31.1.70:9092
>   INFO:kafka.cluster:Group coordinator for datadog is BrokerMetadata(nodeId=1, host=u'kafka-broker1.ap-south-1.staging.internal', port=9092, rack=None)
>   INFO:kafka.coordinator:Discovered coordinator 1 for group datadog
>   INFO:kafka.conn:: connecting to 172.31.1.66:9092
>   INFO:kafka.coordinator.consumer:Revoking previously assigned partitions set([]) for group datadog
>   INFO:kafka.coordinator:(Re-)joining group datadog
>   INFO:kafka.consumer.subscription_state:Updating subscribed topics to: [u'events']
>   INFO:kafka.coordinator:Joined group 'datadog' (generation 843) with member_id kafka-python-1.3.5-e3c25fb3-39ea-4550-845f-9b663355b4f5
>   INFO:kafka.coordinator:Successfully joined group datadog with generation 843
>   INFO:kafka.consumer.subscription_state:Updated partition assignment: []
>   INFO:kafka.coordinator.consumer:Setting newly assigned partitions set([]) for group datadog

When I start second instance first instance get partition assigned and second instance have 0 partition assigned and have same info log as first instance before starting second instance.

below is the info log of first instance after second instance started.

> INFO:kafka.coordinator.consumer:Setting newly assigned partitions set([]) for group datadog
>   WARNING:kafka.coordinator:Heartbeat failed for group datadog because it is rebalancing
>   WARNING:kafka.coordinator:Heartbeat failed ([Error 27] RebalanceInProgressError); retrying
>   INFO:kafka.coordinator.consumer:Revoking previously assigned partitions set([]) for group datadog
>   INFO:kafka.coordinator:(Re-)joining group datadog
>   INFO:kafka.coordinator:Skipping heartbeat: no auto-assignment or waiting on rebalance
>   INFO:kafka.coordinator:Joined group 'datadog' (generation 843) with member_id kafka-python-1.3.5-ddb66185-c615-4f31-9729-9384131f24c9
>   INFO:kafka.coordinator:Elected group leader -- performing partition assignments using range
>   INFO:kafka.coordinator:Successfully joined group datadog with generation 843
>   INFO:kafka.consumer.subscription_state:Updated partition assignment: [TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=0), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=1), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=2), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=3), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=4), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=5), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=6), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=7), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=8), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=9)]
>   INFO:kafka.coordinator.consumer:Setting newly assigned partitions set([TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=6), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=7), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=8), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=9), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=0), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=1), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=2), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=3), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=4), TopicPartition(topic=u'events', partition=5)]) for group datadog

**We always have 1 consumer instance with unassigned partitions on all the cases,  last consumer instance always have 0 partition assigned**

**Below are the screenshot for the same **

[No partitions assigned to first consumer instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zzrW.png)

[No partitions assigned to last consumer instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxxxO.png)

**We also suspect clustering of kafka. When we had only 1 kafka node partition assignment to consumer instance and re-balancing was working fine. But after going into multi-node cluster we are facing this issue**

Comment: did you figure out the root cause?